# Underline colored text with linebreak

Tags: color, line-breaking, ulem, underline

I would like to underline colored text with a black line, and preserve line breaking. My best solution so far is using `\uline` from the `ulem` package. However, I cannot get my desired result. My attempts are:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

This is a long text. This is a long text. 
\color{red}\uline{This is underlined text. 
This is underlined text. This is underlined text.}\color{black} 
This is a long text. This is a long text. 

This is a long text. This is a long text. 
\uline{\color{red}This is underlined text. 
This is underlined text. \color{black}} 
This is a long text. This is a long text. 

This is a long text. This is a long text. 
\textcolor{red}{\uline{This is underlined text. 
This is underlined text. }} 
This is a long text. This is a long text. 

This is a long text. This is a long text. 
\uline{\textcolor{red}{This is underlined text. 
This is underlined text. }} 
This is a long text. This is a long text. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, every attempt has a flaw.

Is there a solution to this? Many thanks!

**EDIT:**

I am now using the `cloze` package, which does not have the shortcomings above and has not let me down yet. It is definitely an option for everyone who can switch to LuaLaTeX.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) did you read the ulem manual? This seems to be mentions in section 2. Ahh, no that makes the line red. Nevermind

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is just a command that gives red text underlined with black line, then this might work

```
\newcommand\reduline{\bgroup\color{red}\markoverwith
{\textcolor{black}{\rule[-0.5ex]{2pt}{0.4pt}}}\ULon}
```

If not, don't get your hopes up too hight, things get complicated when you parse in the way `\ulem` does.

BTW: who is even using underlining these days?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I use underlining for cloze texts. But I might switch to LuaLaTeX now because of a very nice `cloze` package...

Comment: @FlorianL: The usual way to appreciate the work of users here is to upvote and accept answers, instead of leaving a `Thank you` comment only!